# Кудеяр-атаман

Tags: славянизмы, ономастика

Все помнят песню:
*Было двенадцать разбойников,

Был Кудеяр атаман.

Много разбойники пролили

Крови честных христиан!*
Меня интересует имя Кудеяр. Корень "-яр", я ним все понятно, а вот первая часть имени что означает?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Имя Кудеяр, по Фасмеру, происходит от персидского Xudāyār — «возлюбленный Богом»,могло быть названием тюркской должности сборщика податей. По другой версии, Кудеяр — Кудя Ярый, т.е. Кудин Ярый. Кудин – это форма церковного имени Акиндин (с греческого «безопасный»). Но большинство историков согласны и с тем, что имя Кудеяр (Худояр) — татарского происхождения. У Карамзина упоминается крымский мурза Кудояр, который в 1509 году очень грубо обошелся с русским послом Морозовым, назвав его «холопом». С тем же именем известны послы крымский и астраханский. Но, как нередко бывало в прошлом, от татар это имя могло быть усвоено и русскими. 
 http://btula.ru/fullbrend_84.html